# Cast an Object into a class

Tags: java, eclipse, class, subclass

I'm trying to cast an Object into a class instance. The Object of the classes instance should of course inherit all the methods.

So here's my problem in sample code (2) because I can't exactly explain what I mean:

```
Class Fish {}
Class Dog {}

class Instances() {

    private Fish fish = new Fish();
    private Dog dog = new Dog();

    public Object getInstance(String className) {

        if( className.equals("fish") ) 

            return fish;

        else

            return dog;

    }

}

class test() {

    Instances in = new Instances();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 1: works (transmits all the methods of fish)
        Fish fish = (Fish)in.getInstance("fish");

        // 2: doesn't work (fishObj only has access to the methods of an object and can't access the methods of Fish!)
        Object fishObj = null;
        fishObj = (Fish)in.getInstance("fish");

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think it should have access to `Fish` methods if you're accessing it through an `Object` reference?

Comment: You already know how to write the code that works (1), so what are you asking?

Comment: @Eran because the methods in both of these Classes are doing a similar task and they have the same name. I want to load the class which I require currently

Comment: Probably you wanna return a method with different possible return type, right?

Comment: If you want to use `Fish` methods, you have to store it as a `Fish`, or cast it _in the same line_ to a `Fish` (e.g. `((First) in.getInstance("fish")).swim()`.  There's no way around that.

Comment: @Aurus Sounds like you want both classes to implement the same interface (containing the common methods) and change the return type of `getInstance` to be that interface.

Comment: Well my intention was to return these instances as an Object because I didn't care which class has been returned by getInstance(). The class returned by getInstance() has no impact on which methods I call afterwards.

Comment: The code won't compile, correct the syntax class test() {

Comment: Its just a sample code because I didn't know how to explain my issue correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign an object reference to a variable, any further operations you'll do with the reference variable are limited to the ones that are defined for its type.

So you can assign a `Fish` to an `Object` variable. But as long as you use the `Object` variable, you can only use methods that are defined in `Object`, such as `toString()`, `hashCode()` etc.

But you noted in your comments that you want to run a similar method in two classes. I assume that means your `Dog` and `Fish` classes have a method with similar names, parameters and return type, for example `getLegCount()` which would return `4` for `Dog` and `0` for `Fish`.

When this situation arises, you either have to declare both types as subclasses of another class, that has the required method:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    public abstract int getLegCount();

}

class Fish extends Animal {

    @Override
    public int getLegCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then the return type from your `getInstance()` should be `Animal`, not `Object`. And you put the result in an `Animal` variable, and then you can use the `getLegCount()` method.

Another option is to define the required common methods as an interface. It works the same way, and is preferable if there are no implementation details in the expected `Animal` type, only method definitions:

```
public interface Animal {

    int getLegCount();

}

class Fish implements Animal {
    @Override
    public int getLegCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Again, you would declare your return type from `getInstance` as `Animal` and your variable as `Animal` rather than `Object`.

Comment: Both of your answers are exactly what I was looking for, even though I formulated my question wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The java compiler will prevent you from using any methods on `fishObj` other than those of `Object`, because you declared your variable `fishObj` to be of type `Object`. The compiler can't predict what type of object will actually be referenced by that variable at run time, so it goes by the declaration.

Of course, you and I can figure out that `fishObj` will be holding a reference to a `Fish` at the moment the method is invoked, but figuring such things out in general is not always possible, and the Java compiler doesn't try.

Your cast does nothing. It informs the compiler that the value of the expression is in fact `Fish`, but then you assign that value to a variable of type `Object`, and nothing has changed in terms of how the compiler views that variable. (The only possible impact of your cast would be if `#getInstance` actually returned something that was not a `Fish`, in which case you'd get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.)

You can use Java's reflection classes to get at methods of the object that are not accessible via the variable's declared type. E.g.:

```
fishObj.getClass().getMethod("swim").invoke(fishObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at some of your code:

```
Object fishObj = null;
fishObj = (Fish)in.getInstance("fish");
```

So why can you assign an Object of the class Fish, to a variable with the datatype Object ?
In Java, every class derives from the class Object, so Object is the superclass of every class. We can assign objects of a subclass, to variables of a superclass. That's just what you are doing here.

```
fishObj = (Fish)in.getInstance("fish");
```

You assign an Object of the class Fish to the variable fishObj. This is possible because Fish extends Object (even though you didn't note it explicitly).
So we could say that fishObj has the static type Object (the general datatype in this case), and the dynamic type Fish (the Object which is assigned to the variable).

The static type defines which methods are accessible, while the dynamic type defines how the methods are behaving.

Now what does that mean ? Lets take a look at the [Oracle Documentation for the class Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).
We can see that it has a variety of methods like hashCode() or equals(). All these Methods can be called if the static type is Object, because every subclass needs to have these methods. So no matter what happens, the call shouldn't fail.

Let's say that your class Fish has the method swim() and take a look at some code again.

```
Object fishObj = new Fish();
```

So whats the static and what's the dynamic type here ? 
Object would be the static type, fish the dynamic type again. 
Now we wan't to do the following call.

```
fishObj.swim(); //won't work
```

Why is that so ? The class of the static type, Object, doesn't have a method called swim(). So we cannot say for sure that every Object we could assign to the variable fishObj would certainly have the mehtod swim() implemented.

Summed up we can say, that since your static type is Object, specific methods of the class Fish are being hidden from you, to ensure that calls on the Object assigned to the Variable fishObj will always work.

Comment: My first answer to my question here, so please excuse if there is some stuff that isn't fully fleshed out ;)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    Object fishObj = null;
>     fishObj = (Fish)in.getInstance("fish");
> ```

The object is cast to a Fish with (Fish), but as your reference is an Object reference, it is then widened back to Object, hence those are the only methods you see.

Answer (score 0):

```
((Fish)fishObj ).printFish();
```

First of all ,your Instances in = new Instances();
should be static, since you are using it in a static variable

You have assgineed an Fish object to a basic java Object

Answer (score 0):

This is called Runtime polymorphism or Dynamic Method Dispatch is a process in which a call to an overridden method is resolved at runtime rather than compile-time. [More](http://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java)